# My bitcoins are stuck I need help please

Tags: blockexplorer

Ok so I was transfering bitcoins from my wallet on my phone to a friend's computer wallet and I'm pretty sure his address changed halfway​ through because his address is no longer the same and the bitcoins are lost now and I'm so confused, the transactions are still unconfirmed but I don't know how to get them back or get them to the right address it's using blockexplorer here's the link to the transactions anyway https://blockexplorer.com/tx/eafacd02739a473a454c73502400eed4d77b0fc6ae0a96752cd2503274f87309